# How to store PHP Sessions in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, session

Greetings, I need a php class or a list of functions for **session_set_save_handler()**

There are too many visitors, so the fastest code is needed.

P.S. I can't use Memcached because it isn't installed on my hosting

Comment: I fail to see the *question* :-S

Comment: Also have a look at [MySQL’s *MEMORY* Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Answer (score 2):

People here are most likely not going to write a full MySQL session handler for you. But it might not be the best solution anyway:

You need something really fast? Then the answer is Memcached.
Another solution would be storing data client-side in signed cookies. The cryptographic signature ensures the user cannot tamper with the cookie data. But that would still increase the bandwidth needed of course.

---

For the memcached solution, simply install the [memcached extension from PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) and then enable the memcached session handler in your code:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcache');
ini_set('session.save_path', '...');
```

See e.g. http://www.ducea.com/2009/06/02/php-sessions-in-memcached/ for what do use as the "save path".

Comment: +1 for storing session with Memcache. AFAIK, on php.net/session_set_save_handler there's example code on how to store in MySQL, not to mention there are numerous examples if Google is put to work :)

Comment: ok, but i haven't worked with it before. Give a link to good manual, or maybe there is somebody who can give me examples

Comment: Do a google search for "php mysql session". Here is one such result: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html

Comment: @ThiefMaster i've found out that Memcached isn't installed on my hosting and can't be

Comment: `many visitors so the fastest code is needed` and `shared hosting` do not play along very well.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a lot of speed and have actual access to hardware then you might want to look at in memory caching. Memcached has came quite away and you can use it for sessions.